# Confirm message at run time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to show confirm message box but after some calculations in code?
how can I show confirm message at run time?
thanks

Comment: Could you expand the background information a bit?  What kind of code?  Server side or client side?

Answer (score 2):

Button's OnClientClick event you can write a javascript code like this :

```
OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure')"
```

And if users click yes, there will be page refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

On the onClientClick tag (in the aspx file) u can write

```
confirm('your message');
```

and onClick tag reference it to function in code-behind where you can write the function which will only be executed on OK click of the messagebox.

This is assuming the question is regarding asp.net